# Get highest number from inputs

Tags: c#, arrays, max, highest, console.readline

I need a programm, where I can type in numbers and in the end it gives me the highest number.
Why doesn't it work like that? What do I need to change?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] input = new double[12];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" Type in {0} number:", i);
            input = [Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("The highest number is {0}", input.Max(element => Math.Abs(element)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to store all of the inputs entered. Just store the maximum number entered so far and update it only if the user enters a larger number.

Comment: I think it should be input[i]

Comment: First, you need to be specific about what's not working for you. The code you posted doesn't compile. But what part are you actually having trouble with?

Comment: `i <= 12` will not work for `double[12]` use `i < 12`. your max index is 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it so its converting to double and also setting to each individual element

```
 input[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

and then change this because arrray starts at 0

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
```

Comment: No problem arrays are kind of confusing when your first get started.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashad Shanto said you must use `Convert.ToDouble` and you must use `input[i]` instead of `input`. So your code should look like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] input = new double[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" Type in {0} number:", i);
            input[i] = [Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())];
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("The highest number is {0}", input.Max(element => Math.Abs(element)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to convert to double instead of int, unless non-integer input is actually expected. Of course, in that case there's also no need for the array to be `double[]` instead of `int[]`, so who really knows what the OP actually needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @artokai mentioned you don't need to store all entered numbers.

Try the following:

```
  double heighest = Double.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" Type in {0} number:", i);
        double input = (Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input > heighest)
            heighest = input

    }
    Console.WriteLine("The highest number is {0}", highest);
```

Comment: The above assumes no negative inputs. Also, the square bracket before `Convert` doesn't belong.

Comment: The above also assumes that only a double value will be entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Is the requirement to have a Double or Int? Anyways, you can just simple store the highest number each time a new number is entered by doing a simple comparison.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var currentNumber = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" Type in {0} number: ", i);

        var number = Console.ReadLine();
        int result;

        if (int.TryParse(number, out result))
        {
            if (currentNumber < result)
            {
                currentNumber = result;
            }   
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The highest number is {0}", currentNumber);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```